# Site running from accidental upload of core in subdirectory

Tags: installation

Several months ago I accidentally uploaded the folder containing Drupal 6.25 core files to sites/all/modules.

The site now sees that folder as the base install and ignores the installation in the site root.  How can I safely get Drupal to look at the files in the site root as the base install and delete these files?   I tried simply deleting them when I did it and it takes down the site with a configuration error.

Configuration error:  500 - Internal server error - neither front end or back end will load

Comment: Could you post that configuration error? It'll probably help with isolating the problem

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar incident where someone had put a second set of core modules in a second folder called "modules" inside the main modules directory.  As a result Drupal was running off of the `system.module` located in `modules/modules/system`.  This made updating the site problematic.

The only way I fixed it was by dumping the database as a text file (.sql), editing the `modules/modules` file paths in the systems table, then re-importing, overwriting the database.  You may also be able to do this via MySQL commands or using an interface such as phpMyAdmin.  You should also look at [my other answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41389/migration-failed/41398#41398) about steps taken when editing the database. (*You would almost think that cowboy edits of the database is all I do everyday*)

Know that editing the database is not best practice, but sometimes it is the only fix.  Make sure that you should have a backup in case you mess things up, which in most likely happen on our first attempt.

Comment: This is the road I was headed down but I was hoping for a simpler solution!